# Select top * from 2 table orderb by some field

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 table like this

[Info]

[image]

[Score]

[image]

I want to `select top3 * orderby score` in May DESC 
the result should be look like this.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In what table you storing Score?

Comment: i think i have to union 2 table then sum score and then select top 3 but idk how to write a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a JOIN on both tables in a derived table with a SUM on Score and order on that

```
SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM(
SELECT
    I.User_Id, I.[Name], I.Age, Score = SUM(S.Score)
FROM
    Info I
INNER JOIN
    Score S On S.User_Id = I.User_Id
WHERE MONTH(S.[DATE]) = 5 --May (however I suspect this might not be a DATE object)
GROUP BY
    I.User_Id, I.[Name], I.Age
) X
ORDER BY X.Score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, You can use join statement.

```
SELECT TOP(3) a.user_id, a.Name, a.Age, b.Score FROM Users a JOIN Score b On a.user_id=b.user_id Order By b.Score desc
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will be helpfull.

```
SELECT TOP 3 S.User_Id, SUM(S.Score) Score, U.Name, U.Age
FROM Info U
INNER JOIN Score S ON U.User_Id = S.User_Id
WHERE MONTH(S.Date) = 5 --Only May Month.
GROUP BY S.User_Id, U.Name, U.Age
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```